# PDF/UA with itext7 EventHandler is not read out loud

Tags: java, itext, accessibility, itext7, screen-readers

i recently started working with iText and have the requirement that the pdf must comply with a PDF/UA standard in order to ensure accessibility. With the setTagged method and a few other configurations, for example an alternative text for my graphic, most of the work was already done. Unfortunately, the screenreader does not read my footer.

this is what my accessibility configurations look like:

```
pdf.setTagged();
        pdf.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("de"));
        pdf.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdf.getDocumentInfo();
        info.setTitle("pdfTitel");
```

this is how i created the footer:

```
private static class TableFooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
        private final Table table;

        public TableFooterEventHandler(Table table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event currentEvent) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) currentEvent;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);

            Canvas canvas1 = null;
            try {
                canvas1 = new Canvas(canvas, new Rectangle(68, 30, page.getPageSize().getWidth() - 105, 42)).add(table);
            } finally {
                if (canvas1 != null) {
                    canvas1.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is how i actually add it:

```
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new TableFooterEventHandler(footerTable));
```

after that i close the whole document and return the outputstream like that:

```
 document.close();

 return os;
```

When debugging, I noticed that the event handler seems to be called only after the document has been closed. Nevertheless, the footer appears on the pdf, but as I said, it is not read out by the screenreader. What could be the reason for this?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you share an example PDF generated by your code for analysis? Possibly all material added in such an event handler by default is tagged as Artifact...